# AWS Glue Crawler naming convention

Tags: aws-glue

I have a number of items in an s3 path that I'm trying to crawl (using a root path of `s3://my-bucket/somedata/`)

```
s3://my-bucket/somedata/20180101/data1/stuff.txt.gz
s3://my-bucket/somedata/20180101/data2/stuff.txt.gz
s3://my-bucket/somedata/20180101/data1.sql
s3://my-bucket/somedata/20180101/data2.sql  
s3://my-bucket/somedata/20180102/data1/stuff.txt.gz
s3://my-bucket/somedata/20180102/data2/stuff.txt.gz
...
```

Sometimes we tables are named according to the date pattern (e.g. `20180101`); sometimes they are named according to the leaf level 'folder' (e.g. `data1`), sometimes the file (e.g. `data1.sql`), and when there are conflicts it seems that Glue just appends a unique identifier to the table name (e.g. `data1_c17b2f988649f2171b24b1d35da7f2b4`).

What is the logic here? Are these names deterministic? Are there patterns I should use for structuring my data so that the crawler will catalog things in some logical order?

Comment: Any solution for this? I have all the parquet files with the same schema in a folder lets say A. My crawler is creating a table with weird suffix like A_d6gw2y3h83737hfj

Comment: @Tula my solution and guidance is "don't use Glue crawler" - at least in this way. I find it is much more trouble that it is worth. I do sometimes use it for schema discovery, but I will typically retrieve the schema and use it to create / name tables in a  way that makes more sense.

Answer (score -2):

You need to standardize the path to get the name correctly e.g.

```
s3://my-bucket/Customer/Customer_20180101/customer.csv 
s3://my-bucket/Customer/Customer_20180102/customer.csv 
s3://my-bucket/Customer/Customer_20180103/customer.csv 
s3://my-bucket/Customer/Customer_20180104/customer.csv 
s3://my-bucket/Customer/Customer_20180105/customer.csv
```

Will load all the files in Customer table using Glue crawler, once you point the crawler to Customer folder on s3

Comment: It does not answer the question. You cannot expect that data be provided in an ideal way every time. Crawler should be agnostic to the way the paths are provided. It is really buggy in the way it creates the tables. If the folder contains more than one file, it creates tables with the file names in them. If the folder contains only one file, it creates the table with just the folder name. This cannot be called consistency.

Comment: That is your choice. If you standardize you can provide it. Well it works for us in production.